# Exchange 2010 - How to access the archived content using API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

These days I am investigating whether we can access the archived content present in Exchange 2010 using Web Services or server side API.

I need to build a connector against Exchange 2010 and retrieve all the content withing Exchnage 2010. Is this possible?

I have seen the below blog, which says that there is no EWS API to access the archives.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pcreehan/archive/2010/03/04/how-to-programmatically-access-exchange-2010-archive-mailboxes.aspx

Instead we need to use MAPI to access these archived content.

Can someone tell me if Microsoft introduced API to access the archives recently. Or

Can someone point me to some good examples on How to use MAPI to access the archived content from a Java application(or .net)?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use EWS. In 2010 SP1 it's just a matter of specifying the ArchiveMailbox as the well-known-folder-id. Just do a FindItem under the archivemailboxroot folder ...